# Why would you do that?

Tags: meaning

When my friend say

> I'm gonna wear weird costume,

could I say

> Why would you do that?

in future meaning?

When my friend say

> I took your panties yesterday,

could I say

> Why would you do that?

too? in past situation?

Comment: Yes. Both of those work just fine.

Comment: When your friend says "I took your panties yesterday," you *could* say "Why would you do that?" **I** would say, "....Um...you can keep them."

Comment: "Why would [...]" is a construct that transcends tenses and hovers above them.

Comment: @MortimerBallsack: Not everyone is as generous as you.

Comment: Ha, I didn't actually have generosity in mind. If your friend is odd enough to take your panties (and *tell* you they took them), would you really want those panties returned?

Comment: @MortimerBallsack I would agree with you but I don't think it's odd if it's in the situation of having sexual relations with the other person. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @anonymous "I took your panties" and "I took off your panties" sound like two different actions to me.

Answer (score 2):

*Would* is a [Modal Auxiliary Verb](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/592408/15299), a group of auxiliary verbs with peculiar properties. One of them is that they don't have any tense, so the normal mode of an English auxiliary verb is not open to them. Normally, the first auxiliary in the [verb chain] inflects for tense:

- *The model [**has** been being photographed] for hours now.*

The auxiliaries *do, be, have,* and *get* all inflect for present and past tense, like all verbs in English:

- *He **is** not here today. ~ He **was** not here yesterday.*
- *He **doesn't** need any money now. ~ He **didn't** need any money then.*
- *He **hasn't** realized it yet. ~ He **hadn't** realized it yet.*
- *He **gets** married tomorrow. ~ He **got** married yesterday.*

But modal auxiliaries **don't** inflect for any tense, present or past:

- *He **must** leave tomorrow,* but not **He **musted** leave yesterday*
- *He **should** leave now,* but not **He **shoulded** leave yesterday*

Since there are only two tenses in English and neither is marked on modals, they're considered to be tenseless. There is no "future tense" in English, no matter what you've been told in school, since all modals can refer to any time -- *will* is another modal auxiliary and behaves like the rest of them).

So you can say "Why would you do that?" about **any** event someone has done, or is doing right now, or is considering doing. It's all "would-be", and that's timeless.

Comment: It seems to me that ***would*** implies "not here, not now, not true,..." (perhaps somewhere else, in the past or future, or "timelessly" in some alternate reality). So for example *Why would you hit me?* could imply *Why **did** you hit me?* (in the past) or *Why **will / might** you hit me?* (in future or possible alternative circumstances). But I can't easily envisage it applying to something someone is doing right now *(Why **are you hitting** me?)*. Maybe I'd be expecting *Why would you be hitting me?* for that one, I dunno (sounds a bit "Irish" to me! :).

Answer (score 1):

> Why would you do that?

is less about tenses and more about expressing a somewhat negative surprise or amazement, sometimes enhanced by adding ***ever***:

> Why would you ***ever*** do that?

It is in fact part of a conditional sentence in which the ***if clause*** is omitted but implied. The implied part could be for example:

> - If you were in your right mind, ...
> - If you were my real friend... etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, "would" is not indicating an action in the future.

This is an example of the [second conditional](http://www.englishgrammarsecrets.com/secondconditional/menu.php). The second conditional is used for unlikely events. The events you describe may very well be unlikely, depending on the context.

This kind of question might be better asked at the [English Language Learners Stackexchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what exactly you are trying to express.  The key thing to have in mind it the difference between expressing something as 'actual' and expressing something as potential, doubtful or at least not certain.  Latin and ancient Greek verbs had special modes, subjunctive and optative (known for these two languages as 'moods' along with the - to us - more common 'indicative' mood), to express things as not actual in some way.  English does not have these.  It has, instead a modal version of the auxiliary, *would*, or sometimes *could*.

So in the present case, where an intention to wear weird costume, the addressee uses the modal form of the auxiliary to express a kind of disbelief:  that dressing like this is so inappropriate, odd or unlike the person that 'would' is used as opposed to 'why are you going to do that?'.

In the second case, the same response, using 'would' is still standard English.  It expresses a sort of shocked or appalled disbelief.  Or they might have said 'how **could** you have done that?', which brings with it a sense of rebuke, as in "I thought I knew you better than that."

This answer is not in terms of the more conventional notion of 'first', 'second' etc conditionals.  It is simpler to understand in terms of what is going on.